# Getting a directory in a HDFS compatible format

Tags: hadoop

I wanted to know about how to get a directory on my cluster (i.e MapR) in HDFS compatible format. I want to use this for saving spark checkpoint files. Do I need to run `hdfs dfs -ls`

Comment: you mean, you want to copy hdfs directory from cluster to your local filesystem?

Comment: No, I want to know if a directory in the cluster supports HDFS.